# Using 3rd Party AAR in React-Native Android App

Tags: react-native, aar

I am attempting to build a React-Native Android app that utilizes functionality provided by a 3rd party's AAR but am unclear as to both the process in general as well as the required specifics.

I have successfully built an Android Studio app using this AAR.

And, I have scoured the documentation here (and postings elsewhere): https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial but remain unclear as to the correct process.

My initial attempts have centered around trying to find the correct "implementation" and/or "compile" commands in the gradle files coupled with the correct "import" statement(s) in the source file(s).

I had assumed getting those correct would afford access to the classes in the AAR, but after numerous unsuccessful attempts am now wondering if there is something more that needs done.

For example, do I need to construct a bridge module as described here: https://medium.com/@yushulx/react-native-bridging-modules-for-android-from-scratch-c651eeee7872 ?

Based on the few questions/answers I found on this topic, I have placed this code in the "allprojects" section of my top-level build.gradle file:

`flatDir {
      dirs 'libs'}
    }`

...and have included the following in the "dependencies" section of the build.gradle file:

`fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.aar')
 .each { File file ->
  dependencies.add("compile", [
    name: file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with { it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name }, 
    ext: 'aar'])
        }`

...and have included various forms of "import" statements in my app.js file, like:

`import {EENMediaPlayerListener} from 'EENSDK';...`

When I execute "react-native run-android" I receive the following error message:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `EENSDK` from `C:\Users\Chuck\EE\App.js`: Module `EENSDK` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

EENSDK.aar is located in the 'C:\Users\Chuck\EE\android\app\libs' directory.

If I remove the "import" statement, it compiles without errors.

### So, do I just have the "compile", "implementation", and "import" statements wrong, or is there something more (and if so, where can I read about that)?